# Invoking SageMaker endpoint failed since timm library was not found in the environment

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface

I deployed a Hugging Face `facebook/detr-resnet-50` model using the official code provided here:
https://huggingface.co/facebook/detr-resnet-50?sagemaker_deploy=true

Then, I tried to use the `predictor` variable to invoke this endpoint:

```py
from sagemaker.serializers import DataSerializer
    
predictor.serializer = DataSerializer(content_type='image/x-image')

# Make sure the input file "cats.jpg" exists
with open("image.jpg", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()
predictor.predict(data)
```

It failed with the following error:

```
ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from primary with message "{
  "code": 400,
  "type": "InternalServerException",
  "message": "\nDetrForObjectDetection requires the timm library but it was not found in your environment. You can install it with pip:\n`pip install timm`. Please note that you may need to restart your runtime after installation.\n"
}
```

I tried to install `timm` on the environment where I ran the invoke call (I'm also tried to restart this environment) but it seems like this package is missing from the SageMaker endpoint.
How can I add it as part of the model deployment?

Comment: This is something to do with the model package in HF hub. You can download the model files and deploy it from s3.  This way you can also have a requirements.txt and add additional dependencies.
 https://github.com/huggingface/notebooks/blob/main/sagemaker/10_deploy_model_from_s3/deploy_transformer_model_from_s3.ipynb